# Firebase Storage Warning: downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I just updated my project to the latest version of Firebase Storage and I am now getting a warning: 
downloadURL() is deprecated: Use StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion() to obtain a current download URL.

I looked at the Firebase image upload documentation but it still references using `downloadURL()` which is now depreciated. In the code below I am getting the download URL of the image as a String. The code works but now to be updated since `downloadURL()` is depreciated

```
uploadProfilePicTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in

  guard let profilePicStringURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString else { return }
  ...
```

Here is my attempted updated. I tried the code below with the new `downloadURLWithCompletion()`  but something in `snapshot.metadata?.storageReference?` is returning nil so I am not able to retrieve the url String. Does anyone know how to use the new `downloadURLWithCompletion()` appropriately below?

```
uploadProfilePicTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
  snapshot.metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL { URL, error in
    if let urlString = URL?.absoluteString {
      // Do something
    } else {
      return
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint and take a look at what `snapshot` contains?

Comment: @Niamh Yes I have. storageReference is returning Nil but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically not using the metadata but instead just getting the url after the success of your observe event. Since it's successful and you know it's there, you can download the URL. It's there in their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) to 'Generate a download URL'.  Below, I'm assuming your StorageReference is uploadProfilePicTask.

```
uploadProfilePicTask.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        if let downloadUrl = url {
                           // Make you download string
                           let downloadString = downloadUrl.absoluteString
                        }
                    } else {
                   // Do something if error
                    }
           })
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation of what your code is doing. Code only answers are discouraged here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I fixed it with this code:

```
    uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
        guard let imageURL = snapshot.metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {                      //add all you want

            }
        }) else { return }
        let imageStr = String(describing: imageURL)
        DBService.manager.updatePhoto(profileImageUrl: imageStr)
        AuthService.manager.updatePhoto(urlString: imageStr)
    }

}
```