# Firebase Storage downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Normally I am updating image with url to firebase storage with:

```
Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(fileName).putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) {
    [weak self] (metadata, err) in
    guard let strongSelf = self else {
        return
    }

    if let err = err {
        print(err)
    }

    guard let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString else {
        return
    }

    ProfilePhotoHandler.Instance.addPhotoUrl(withUrl: profileImageUrl)
}
```

But right now `Xcode 9.3` show warning:

```
downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()
```

Firebase docs still shows old way. Does anyone can help me how to handle it now?

Comment: Can't you just ignore it? (untill the docs get updated) It is only a warning after all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765128/firebase-storage-warning-downloadurl-is-deprecated-use-storagereference-do

Comment: Have you tried updating the Firebase pods?

Answer (score 5):

With the changes in swift 5.0, metadata no longer has a method of downloadURL.

Instead you must do something along the lines of:

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("message_images").child(fileName)

storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in

        if let err = err {
            print(err)
        }
    storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download url:", error!)
        return
    } else {
       //Do something with url
        }

      })
    })
}
```

Hope this helps. You can also take a look at: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798766/firebase-storage-downloadurl-is-deprecated-use-storagereference-downloadurl) answer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007881/image-url-in-firebasestorage-does-not-exist-responseerrordomain-com-google-htt/52028008#52028008) answer, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281266/%E2%80%A6) answer or just look at the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I fixed it with this code:

```
uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
        guard let imageURL = snapshot.metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {
            }
        }) else { return }
        let imageStr = String(describing: imageURL)
        DBService.manager.updatePhoto(profileImageUrl: imageStr)
        AuthService.manager.updatePhoto(urlString: imageStr)
    }

}
```