# Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swift4, firebase-storage

I just updated Firebase Storage to 5.0.0 and it looks like `metadata.downloadURL()` is not recognized anymore. (`Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'`)

Though after looking in the documentation it should still be available :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata#/c:objc(cs)FIRStorageMetadata(im)downloadURL

The project was cleaned & rebuilt already.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Can you try [Google Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url)

```
// Create a reference to the file you want to download
let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// Fetch the download URL
starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the only solution now. Though I don't get why the URL is not accessible from the StorageMetadata instance anymore.

Comment: the documentation says it would be ```storageRef.downloadURL```instead of ```starsRef.downloadURL```but it doesn't make any sense to me it should be starsRef .?

Comment: *firebaser here* The download URL used to be included in the metadata of the task, but that was having performance impact while not all users needed it. That's why it now always requires a separate call, so that only users who need the download URL are seeing that performance impact.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, should it be called on ```starsRef```or ```storageRef``` ?  ```starsRef``` would make more sense but the documentation says the contrary

Comment: @DavidSeek 's answer confirms that ```.downloadURL``` should really be called on ```starsRef``` instead of ```storageRef```as said in the documentation, which make much more sense to me

Answer (score 7):

This is my version for Swift 3 / Swift 4.

Explanation of what happens in the code.

This is essentially the same answer as Sh_Khan's. But in his example the User already knows the bucket path. In my example, we get the path from an upload task. This was what has lead me to this question as well as what I think op was looking for as he was looking for `metadata.downloadURL()` replacement.

```
class StorageManagager {


    private let storageReference: StorageReference

    init() {

        // first we create a reference to our storage
        // replace the URL with your firebase URL
        self.storageReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://MYAPP.appspot.com")
    }

    // MARK: - UPLOAD DATA
    open func uploadData(_ data: Data, named filename: String, completion: @escaping (URL? , Error?) -> Void) {

        let reference = self.storageReference.child(filename)
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "ourType" // in my example this was "PDF"

        // we create an upload task using our reference and upload the 
        // data using the metadata object
        let uploadTask = reference.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { metadata, error in

            // first we check if the error is nil
            if let error = error {

                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            // then we check if the metadata and path exists
            // if the error was nil, we expect the metadata and path to exist
            // therefore if not, we return an error
            guard let metadata = metadata, let path = metadata.path else {
                completion(nil, NSError(domain: "core", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unexpected error. Path is nil."]))
                return
            }

            // now we get the download url using the path
            // and the basic reference object (without child paths)
            self.getDownloadURL(from: path, completion: completion)
        }

        // further we are able to use the uploadTask for example to 
        // to get the progress
    }

    // MARK: - GET DOWNLOAD URL
    private func getDownloadURL(from path: String, completion: @escaping (URL?, Error?) -> Void) {

        self.storageReference.child(path).downloadURL(completion: completion)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To link it with @Sh_Khan 's answer, this shows that ```.downloadURL``` should really be called on ```starsRef``` instead of  ```storageRef``` as said in the documentation, which make much more sense to me

Comment: When I try this method, I'm getting errors that Firebase is not yet configured.  I have it in the appDelegate and was working fine until I added the init.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this code in Swift 4.2:

```
let imgData = UIImage.jpegData(self.imageView.image!)

let imageName = UUID().uuidString
let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("pictures/\(imageName).jpg")
let meta = StorageMetadata()
meta.contentType = "image/jpeg"

self.uploadToCloud(data: imgData(0.5)!, ref: ref, meta: meta)
```

UploadToCloud Method:

```
` Method UploadToCloud
func uploadToCloud(data:Data, ref:StorageReference, meta:StorageMetadata) {
    ref.putData(data, metadata: meta) { (metaData, error) in
        if let e = error {
            print("==> error: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else 
        {
            ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                print("Image URL: \((url?.absoluteString)!)")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question pops up for all language searches. Hence for Kotlin, the solution is something of the kind below:

```
val photoRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .reference.child("images/stars.jpg")

// Code ommited - Do some saving - putFile

    photoRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener({ uri ->
                         product.imageUrl = uri.toString()
                     })
```

However, this is not a good solution. You are better off saving the path and then re-constructing the full Url on demand. For example:

```
photoRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener({ uri ->  
            val imagePath = uri.toString()
            // Save to database
        })
```

Now, you can use it later, and only on demand:

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(product.imageUrl).downloadUrl
                    .addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                        String imageUrl = uri.toString()
                        // Load in images
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        guard let uid = user?.user.uid else {
            return
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //Добавляем картинку в firebase. Надо добавить в Pods file pod 'Firebase/Storage' и запустить терминал
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

        // Create a reference to the file you want to download
        let starsRef = storageRef.child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).png")

        let uploadData = self.profileImageView.image?.pngData()

        starsRef.putData(uploadData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
            }
            if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.path {
                let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImage": profileImageUrl]
                self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid: uid, values: values)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Add explanation, please.

Answer (score -6):

If you are stuck in converting URL to string... you can try this

```
url.absoluteString
```