# What is the downloadURL equivalent in FirebaseStorage 3?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have just updated my project's pods and whit that came `FirebaseStorage 3.0.0`

One change is that `StorageMetadata()` does not contain `downloadURL()` anymore. I can't find a migration/changelog.

```
let uploadTask = ref.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { metadata, error in

    if let error = error {

        completion(nil, error)
    }



    if let meta = metadata, let url = meta.downloadURL() { // ... has no member downloadURL 

        completion(url, nil)
    }

}
```

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: see my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281266/metadata-downloadurl-not-recognized-anymore/50281311#50281311

Comment: okay, so then the solution is to use`storageRef.child(metadata.path).downloadURL` to get the url. that is very inconvenient. but thanks.