# Value of type 'StorageMetaData' has no member SWIFT

Tags: swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

Now I tried the answer from the link you send me . but now i get a new error code 
it says
Use of unresolved identifier 'storageRef'

```html
 func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")
    
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75) else { return }
    
    
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    
    starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
        if let error = error {
            // Handle any errors
        } else {
            // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
        }
    }
        }
```

Comment: look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281266/metadata-downloadurl-not-recognized-anymore

Comment: sorry i dont know how to use it... i tried... can you maybe do it i would be very thankful

Comment: when i done it there is a new failure ... it says no member for Saveprofile

Comment: The download URL is no longer available from the metadata, but requires a call to a `StorageReference.downloadUrl`. The linked question shows how to do that. If you've tried that but are having problems making it work, show what you've tried.

Comment: i tried it now .
Please look at the Top i edit it thanks