# Firebase downloadUrl() is deprecated

Tags: swift, firebase

Can you help please with this: 'downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()` to obtain a current download URL.

```
Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename).putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to upload profile image:", err)
                    return
                }
                guard let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString else { return }
                print("Successfully uploaded profile image:", profileImageUrl)
                guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }

                let dictionaryValues = ["username": username, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
                let values = [uid: dictionaryValues]
                Database.database().reference().child("users").updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                    if let err = err {
                        print("Failed to save user info into db:", err)
                        return
                    }

                    print("Successfully saved user info to db")
                })
            })
```

Comment: What problem do you encounter when using `downloadURLWithCompletion` ?

Comment: 'downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion() to obtain a current download URL.

Comment: Precisely, this is why you should use `downloadURLWithCompletion` rather than `downloadURL`

Comment: says: Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURLWithCompletion'

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use \`StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()\` to obtain a current download URL.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005963/downloadurl-is-deprecated-use-storagereference-downloadurlwithcompletion) and [Firebase Storage Warning: downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765128/firebase-storage-warning-downloadurl-is-deprecated-use-storagereference-do)